# jquery ui tabs overlay border when inside a form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, forms, jquery-ui-tabs

There is a draw error when I put a jquery ui tabs inside a form like this:

```
<form>
  <div id="tab-section1">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab1"><span>Principal</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2"><span>Complement</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab1">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

but it show correctly when inside a div:

```
<div>
  <div id="tab-section2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab1"><span>Principal</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2"><span>Complement</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab1">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a bug in jquery ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "draw error" and "overlay border"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing a draw error here is the code for a sample running at http://www.andrewbricker.com/test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
        $( "#tab-section1" ).tabs();
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
  <div id="tab-section1">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab1"><span>Principal</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2"><span>Complement</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab1">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Perhaps you are not successfully pulling a jQuery UI CSS file. I'm not seeing any "draw errors"

Comment: In fact, I was using another css file that was conflicted with jquery.